# functional form for modeling hazard function

Tags: regression, hazard

[image]

What functional form do you suggest to model this hazard function? 
Can it be a quadratic form, even tough it's skewed?

Comment: Does it need to be a parametric function?  If not, you could always simply use the sequence of point estimates you have here, or apply something like a smoothing spline.

Comment: It needs to be a parametric function. Something more parsimonious then the general model. There's a clear rise, peak and decline. So I was thinking quadratic. But it's skewed, the rise is more rapid then the decline. It's this a problem? If so, would you suggest a cubic or quartic form.

Comment: You would presumably want something for which the hazard increases and decreases; so the lognormal, the generalized gamma models are possibilities. If you want additional flexibility, you might look at the generalized F. See [here](http://data.princeton.edu/pop509/ParametricSurvival.pdf) for example

Answer (score 1):

I would say a spline would be the right idea.  You want parsimony, but you also don't want to ignore the structure of the data (for example the spike at two years) which would likely happen with something like a single quadratic or cubic function.  You could either fit the spline directly to the scatterplot of points (which is probably the easier idea at this point), or another common approach would be to estimate a function of the form

$$
h(k) = \frac{e^{s(k)}}{e^{s(k)} + 1}
$$

where $h(k)$ is the hazard function and $s(k)$ is a smooth function.  However, this latter method requires some data manipulation if one wants to use standard statistical techniques, so I wouldn't really recommend it at this point.